# KDE freeze with Ubuntu13.10

Tags: 13.10, kde

I have a new installation of Ubuntu 13.10 on a lenovo laptop, for which I decided to install KDE. After I logged out and in and choosing `KDE plasma workspace`, all worked fine.

But later, when I log into `KDE plasma workspace`, its loads normally, and I see the choosen background and the standard KDE panel at the bottom of the screen. I can move the mouse around, but that's it. I cannot do anything else. Klicking on anything or typing does not do anything, all is frozen. I have to power the laptop off the hard way! I tried several times, without any luck of able to use KDE.

Logging in to the `Ubuntu` standard desktop, on the other hand, works just fine.

How can I fix this behaviour?

Please let me know any log entry, software installation, hardware device etc. you need to know in order to solve this problem (and how I e.g. can figure out the type of graphics card or whatever...).

**Additional information:**

- Extract from `kdm.log`:

  ```
  Loading extension GLX
  klauncher(1266) kdemain: No DBUS session-bus found. Check if you have started the DBUS server. 
  kdeinit4: Communication error with launcher. Exiting!
  kdmgreet(1212)/kdecore (K*TimeZone*): KSystemTimeZones: ktimezoned initialize() D-Bus call failed:  "Not connected to D-Bus server"
  ```
- The suggestion made [here](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=89677) to press `ALT+SHIFT+F12` did not help
- I also renamed each file containing the phrase `plasma` under `.kde/share/config` as suggested [here](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=91019), which also did not resolve my problem. The background image has changed and I saw two terminals open, but locked to the panel at the bottom. I could not open them.
- lspci -v shows the following for the graphics card:

  ```
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
      Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
      Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
      Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
      Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
      I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
      Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
      Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
      Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
      Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
  ```
- New user: If I add a new user, I am able to log-in to the KDE desktop (at least twice).

Comment: Try and look for a failsafe version. Also, to shutdown, you just need to run `sudo shutdown -h now` or `sudo halt`. Create another user as well (You can delete it later), and see if you can login with that user. To find the Graphics Card, run `lshw -c display` or `lspci -v`. Looking at your kdm log, have you changed any settings or installed any extensions?

Comment: I have updated the question. With a new user I have no problems, so it seems to be some setting I have made. But how to find it and reset this particular setting? I have already renamed each file with the phrase `plasma` inside `.kde/share/config`.

Comment: Any other idea? Should I remove kde and reinstall? Should I redo any KDE changes? Anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to remove your KDE settings, you be able to via removing the config files in your home directory. 
If you remove the files `~/.kde` (could also be `~/.kde4`), it should remove the configuration - hence resetting it and hopefully removing any problems with it.

You will also need to remove the KDE files from `~/.config` and `~/.local` - **Don't just remove these files, they are shared directories, and are used by other programs as well.**

*You don't have to remove the files if you want to, you can just rename them or place them elsewhere.*

Hope this helps.

---

When you have a KDE config that works, you can back it up by running this to make a compressed file:

```
tar -cf KDEbackup`date +%y%m%d`.tar '.kde'
```

Or this to simply copy it:

```
cp -r '.kde' KDEbackup`date +%y%m%d`
```

**N.B.** If you are not copying and pasting, note that the things surrounding the `date +%y%m%d` **are not apostrophes** they are [Grave accents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming). The <kbd>`</kbd> key is to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd> on most keyboards. I know this is overly complicated, but it is useful when backing up as it adds in the date automatically. [image: smiley]

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work! But how do I prevent this situation from happening again? Make a Backup of `.kde` each time I reconfigure something? Or some other idea?

Comment: Backing up the `.kde` would work - `shall add commands to my answer as the markdown does not allow me to type them.